# Are separate Javascript Script tags isolated from each others errors?

Tags: javascript, html, runtime-error

First I'll state what I am trying to achieve: I'd like to have some code that connects to my server via websockets. I send messages to the browser to tell it to reload, remotely. I'd like this code (barring it has no errors itself) to not be affected by other page errors, so that I can still hard refresh the page remotely to fix said errors.

In my testing on latest Chrome and iPad safari, if a runtime exception occurs in one script tag, that js execution halts. However, any other javascript in other script tags still runs no problem. Is this expected behaviour, or am I just getting lucky? I've thrown TypeError's, `throw new Error('something')`, and undefined errors, and my other scripts still run fine. I do something like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='reloadCode.js'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='mainApp.js'/>
```

If I throw a bajillion errors in `mainApp.js`, my websocket code still runs and refreshes the page in `reloadCode.js`, even if `mainApp.js` is evaluated first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825992/prevent-javascript-from-stopping-when-error-is-encountered

Answer (score 4):

Ok I just did a test myself to make sure, (I don't think separate JS files should mess each other up from compiling)

I first created a simple HTML page which included 3 JS files.
Here are the JS files

myscript1.js

```
alert("1");
```

myscript2.js

```
alert("2")a;
```

myscript3.js

```
alert("3");
```

Html

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="myscript1.js"></script>
<script src="myscript2.js"></script>
<script src="myscript3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myscript1 and myscript3 are ran, but it doesn't run myscript2 because of an error, so as long as your reloadCode.js works fine then you will be all A-OK

Just to be clear I only got 2 alerts, not 3, this is because `myscript2.js` did not compile.

Comment: Awesome. thanks Canvas and Onilol for the reassurance. As Qix mentioned, if anyone knows of a spec regarding this, that would be extra reassuring.

Comment: I am getting only 2 alerts, basically the browser goes to compile each JS file, so the first one it compiles and then runs the code, it then goes to compile the second one and it breaks, so it just skips over that one and then goes to the third one which then compiles and runs and not a problem at all thehammer :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless they are interacting between them... Then yes they are separated from each other.

Comment: Source? Spec reference?

Answer (score 2):

## Parsing Errors

Adding to the tests in previous answers, it seems the documentation mentions that all errors in a script tag are scoped to that scriptElement and doesn't affect others on the page. For the parsing stages the handling for this is as follows:

> If the script's script is null for scriptElement, then fire an event named error at scriptElement, and return.
>
> If the previous step failed, queue a task to fire an event named error at the element, and return. Otherwise, let url be the resulting URL record.
>
> If the script's script is null for scriptElement, then fire an event named error at scriptElement, and return.

## Handling Runtime Errors

The browser should, once a runtime error has been detected in a script, emit an `error` event on the target `scriptElement`. If this event is not handled then the browser forwards the error to the developer console.

The `error` event has the following interface:

```
interface ErrorEvent : Event {
  constructor(DOMString type, optional ErrorEventInit eventInitDict = {});

  readonly attribute DOMString message;
  readonly attribute USVString filename;
  readonly attribute unsigned long lineno;
  readonly attribute unsigned long colno;
  readonly attribute any error;
};
```

The behavior for handling runtime script errors is:

> When the user agent is to report an exception E, the user agent must report the error for the relevant script, with the problematic position (line number and column number) in the resource containing the script, using the global object specified by the script's settings object as the target. If the error is still not handled after this, then the error may be reported to a developer console.

Source:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#runtime-script-errors

Answer (score 0):

In the first example I wrote three alert() in three script tags separately ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/artamonovdev/3sqLe5m3/6/)). Fired alert('FIRST') and alert('THIRD').

```
<script>alert('FIRST');</script>
<script>errorAlert('SECOND');</script>
<script>alert('THIRD');</script>
```

In the second example I wrote three alert() in one script tag ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/artamonovdev/3sqLe5m3/7/)). Fired only alert('FIRST').

```
<script>
alert('FIRST');
errorAlert('SECOND');
alert('THIRD');
</script>
```