# Why jquery error is skipped on live environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So there was this minor error on production which was there for over a year but never got noticed until recently

This script was run inline

```
<script> 
    var elem_val =  JSON.parse($("#element").val()); 
    // element is not present and hence the bug pops from here
    // some further code
</script>
```

And post that there were further script tags, libs etc.
As I was working on a feature, this error, out of the blues appeared. And when I tried to search the history, it was unnoticed till a year ago.

And suddenly, this was found on the **staging** environment where the app does not move forward due to this error.
However it is STILL working on the **LIVE** environment.

When I took the live codes, the bug was blocking my app on my local machine. I am unable to understand how and why the live environment is working perfectly fine with this bug. How is it able to skip that?

Is it due to some environment setting features which makes this possible? I am using Ruby on Rails for this.

P.S:- All the jquery libraries and stuffs were pre loaded, so if the element does exist, the code should work fine.

Edit:- Dear people, I am not looking for how to fix this. The bug is fixed. What I want to know is the possible reason of the behavior I just observed. The bug was skipped on the **live** environment. Or production server or whatever you would call it. And the bug was **not** skipped on my laptop

Comment: Fix the error, or wrap the statement in a `try ... catch`. An error is an error.

Comment: It would be very helpful if someone could help me with correcting what I want to say

Comment: @Pointy no the try catch thing is not what I am wishing for as an answer. What I am saying is, the error is skipped on live environment, however it blocks the normal functionality of the app on local. I wish to know why this weird behavior is being observed

Comment: If you suppress the error, you could end up by having even worse situation/behavior in the application. It is always best approach to consider the fact, that you might not have that element and adjust your code/logic in appropriate way.

Comment: Nobody can help you because nobody else is familiar with your "live" or "local" or "staging" environments. Errors are not "skipped" in any case.

Comment: Easiest way would be to debug the code on Staging and Production (aka Live) and see first of all what is returned by $("#element").val()

Also it would be very helpful if you had the original error included in OP.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more likely that `#element` is actually present in your production file, which explains why no error is thrown? Then at some point in your dev source, the `#element` was removed recently? I know you said you checked that the line of JS goes back a year but does the non-existence of the element have the same issue?

Comment: @GSazheniuk did you read the full post? `$("#element").val()` just returns `undefined` if `#element` is missing from the DOM

Comment: Guys. Please do read the full post and then give the downvotes. `#element` was not present forever. And the bug is present in all environments

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825992/prevent-javascript-from-stopping-when-error-is-encountered

Comment: `if the element does exist, the code should work fine.`  Eh!!!  If the element does not exist you will get JSON parse error..

Comment: @Keith exactly. It is working!

Comment: No.,  There is something else your missing..

Comment: @Keith I am in fact getting the error. However, that error is not stopping the working of the app. But it does block everything on my laptop

Comment: @GSazheniuk apparently my app does not have that particular code of `window.onerror`. But if it is possible for it to be added when it's on production, I guess that could be a valid answer.

Comment: @Sagar just that you mentioned that it blocks everything on your laptop - do you access live environment from other machine? Than this most probably is due to the difference in the browser versions/configurations. Different browsers can handle script and errors in a different manner. Anyways, this is too broad question and unless you can give us an access to both staging and live apps, I doubt anyone can give you any specific answer on this issue, IMO

Comment: @GSazheniuk is it possible to submit a form even if there are script errors and no validation checks on any of the forms during the on submit event?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if handled asynchronously:

http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/