# React global ErrorBoundary graceful failure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, sentry

I have just created a React ErrorBoundary component as described here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

I would like to use this to catch all unhandled errors on my site and log them in Sentry. My ErrorBoundary component looks like this:

```
import { PureComponent } from 'react';

class ErrorBoundary extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        hasError: false
    };

    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
        this.setState({ hasError: true });
        const captureError = async (error, errorInfo) => {
            const { logErrorWithInfo } = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "sentry" */ '../../utils/sentry');
            logErrorWithInfo(error, errorInfo);
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.hasError) {
          return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
        }
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

export default ErrorBoundary
```

I have placed this component in my `App.js` so that it wraps all child components:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Router>
          <Header />
            <main className="main">
              <Redirects />
            <Routes />
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );
  }
}
```

For testing purposes I am forcing an error in my Homepage scene like so: `throw "Test Error - Ignore!";`.

The issue I have is that I don't want one error in one of the many child components to just break the whole site. I don't want to have to go and wrap every single child component in `<ErrorBoundary></ErrorBoundary>`. The main reason I'm implementing the ErrorBoundary component is for logging rather than dispalying some fancy message about some component failing. I don't really care if something fails I just want to know about it so I can go and sort it out without having to think about how I display things to the user when an error occurs. An error doesn't necessarily mean the child component will fail to render anyway so I still want to give it the chance to do so without just overwriting it with a "something went wrong" message. Is it possible to handle this at a global level?

Comment: `ErrorBoundary` has nothing to do with this. With it or without, your javascript will stop its execution on an rising exception. There is some tricks/hacks which can prevent from stopping the execution, basically `try/catch`, `window.onerror = () => return true`... You can find a lot of them here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825992/prevent-javascript-from-stopping-when-error-is-encountered

Comment: Thanks. I've moved the error handling to `window.onerror` now but for some reason, I'm getting "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component." and the page goes blank after `onerror` has been fired.